# Join three tables with status open or closed

Tags: php, join

I have three tables I wish to inner join by a common column between them.

**client**

```
ClientID    Name
=========   ============
   2          Jaan    
   12         Sajesh
   13         Ruble
```

**clients_of_cases:**

```
ClientsOfCaseID   ClientID    CaseID  
============      ========    ========   
     157             2          2
     139            12          8
     141            12          7
     364            12          225
     11             13           9
     12             13          10
     13             13          11
    312             13          184
```

**ccases**

```
CaseID       IsClosed  
==========   ========    
   2            1
   7            0
   8            1
   9            1
   10           1
   11           1
   184          1
   225          1
```

I need the following :

1. I want to show the clients whose **all cased are closed** (Isclosed=1)
2. Get client with **any case is open**(Isclosed=0)

I build following query

1.

```
SELECT clients.ClientID,clients.Name,ccases.IsClosed 
FROM clients 
    JOIN clients_of_cases ON clients.ClientID=clients_of_cases.ClientID 
    JOIN ccases ON clients_of_cases.CaseID=ccases.CaseID 
WHERE ccases.IsClosed=1 
GROUP BY clients.ClientID
```

2.

```
SELECT clients.ClientID,clients.Name,ccases.IsClosed 
FROM clients 
JOIN clients_of_cases ON clients.ClientID=clients_of_cases.ClientID 
JOIN ccases ON clients_of_cases.CaseID=ccases.CaseID 
WHERE ccases.IsClosed=0 
GROUP BY clients.ClientID
```

But it does not return the required result...

And i get this result:

```
 ClientID  FirstName IsClosed
   ==============================
      12        Sajesh       0




 ClientID  FirstName IsClosed
    ==============================
      2         Jaan         1
      12        Sajesh       1
      13        Ruble        1
```

And wants to get this result:

```
 ClientID  FirstName IsClosed
   ==============================
      12        Sajesh       0

ClientID  FirstName IsClosed
==============================
  2         Jaan         1
  13        Ruble        1
```

Comment: So the first query is already correct? Because your actual result and what you want to get are the same (for the first query)

Comment: bt both results client sajesh is present.if any case of client not closed client will treated as live client otherwise all cases are closed client treated as old clent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both results in one query by comparing the number of closed cases with the total number of cases for each client using this query:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.Name,
    CASE WHEN SUM(cc.IsClosed)=COUNT(cc.IsClosed) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsClosed
FROM client c
LEFT JOIN clients_of_cases coc ON coc.ClientID = c.ClientID
JOIN ccases cc ON cc.CaseID = coc.CaseID
GROUP BY c.ClientID
ORDER BY IsClosed
```

Output:

```
ClientID  Name     IsClosed
12        Sajesh   0 
2         Jaan     1 
13        Ruble    1
```

Note that this query assumes that IsClosed is only ever 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4):

To get all clients all of whose cases are closed, we can try aggregating:

```
SELECT c1.ClientID, c1. Name
FROM client c1
INNER JOIN clients_of_cases c2
    ON c1.ClientID = c2.ClientID
INNER JOIN ccases c3
    ON c2.CaseID = c3.CaseID
GROUP BY c1.ClientID, c1.Name
HAVING SUM(c3.IsClosed) = COUNT(*);
```

We can also use a very similar aggregation approach to find clients having at least one open case:

```
SELECT c1.ClientID, c1. Name
FROM client c1
INNER JOIN clients_of_cases c2
    ON c1.ClientID = c2.ClientID
INNER JOIN ccases c3
    ON c2.CaseID = c3.CaseID
GROUP BY c1.ClientID, c1.Name
HAVING SUM(c3.IsClosed) < COUNT(*);   -- only difference from above is the HAVING clause
```

Though you are aggregating by client in your current approach, the major flaw I see is that you are trying to use the `WHERE` clause to assert restrictions on the open/closed status of the case.  Instead, you need to put that logic into a `HAVING` clause, which then asserts on each client group.